# How take average for these type of data in R

Tags: r

Here is a small sample of my data. The column names are not exactly the same

```html
dat<-read.table (text=" Z1  Gol1    Z2  Gol2    Z3  Gol3    Z4  Gol4
 Azam   2    Smith  3    Moli   1   Dad 0
Azam    2    Goli   3    Sam    2   Moli    0
Moli    4    komi   4    Maz    2   Carr    0
 Mith   2    Goli   4   Maz 2    Moli   0
 Moli   2   Smith   3   Sam 2   Dad 1
Mith    2   Komi    2   Moli    2   Carr    1


", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table for each column

```html
Z1  average1    Z2  average2    Z3  Average3    Z4  Average4
Azam    2   Smith   3    Moli   1.5  Dad    0.5
Moli    3    Goli   3.5  Sam    2    Moli   0
Mith    2   Komi    3    Maz    2   Carr    0.5
```

The logic is each name has been repeated twice and I want to calculate the average goal for each name.

Comment: See `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the unique suffix number at the end of column name in `map`, then do a `group_by/summarise` operation and then bind the columns together with `cbind.fill` from `rowr` (as there are some elements with unequal number of rows)

```
library(rowr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
un1 <- readr::parse_number(names(dat)) %>%
       unique
map(un1, ~ dat %>%
  select(ends_with(as.character(.x))) %>% 
  group_by(across(1)) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), mean, .names = "Average_{.col}"), 
    .groups = 'drop')) %>% 
 { do.call(cbind.fill, c(., list(fill = NA)))}%>%   
 filter(complete.cases(Z1))
#    Z1 Average_Gol1   Z2 Average_Gol2   Z3 Average_Gol3   Z4 Average_Gol4
#1 Azam            2 Goli          3.5  Maz          2.0 Carr          0.5
#2 Mith            2 komi          4.0 Moli          1.5  Dad          0.5
#3 Moli            3 Komi          2.0  Sam          2.0 Moli          0.0
```

---

Or another option is to reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then reshape it back

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
dat %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
         names_sep="(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
     group_by(grp, Z) %>%
     summarise(Average = mean(Gol), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
     mutate(rn = rowid(grp)) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(Z, Average), names_sep = "") %>%
     select(-rn) %>% 
     na.omit
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  Z1    Z2    Z3    Z4    Average1 Average2 Average3 Average4
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Azam  Goli  Maz   Carr         2      3.5      2        0.5
#2 Mith  komi  Moli  Dad          2      4        1.5      0.5
#3 Moli  Komi  Sam   Moli         3      2        2        0
```

Comment: @user330 Do you get a list of 2 columns each with `map(1:4, ~ dat %>%
  select(ends_with(as.character(.x))))`

Comment: @user330 Are you saying that  the `select` step is failing?  Do you have column names with `1` to `4` as the last character

Comment: @user330 can you show some patterns of your actual column name so that i can change the code

Comment: Exactly as you see. The difference is  I have name and surname and with Z1 to Z 8 and Gol1 to Gol8, a overall of 16 columns

Comment: @user330 okay, then you can have `map(1:8, ~ dat %>%..`

Comment: @user330 Can you try the pivot option I just updated

Comment: @user330 Can you check the `str(yourdata)`.  I assume that it is a data.frame and the columns are normal as you showed here

Comment: @user330 That is what I expected.  Are you saying that with pivoting, it is not returning any error or output.  I am a bit confused

Comment: @user330 Is it posible for you to update your post with `dput(head(yourdata))` so that we can test it correctly

Comment: It is exactly the same as you can see above no difference, I have only   ( Z1 .... Z8) and ( Gol1 ... Gol 8). Also I have name and surname for each Z like Ros Molie

Comment: @user330 Then, there may be some package version issues on your end

Comment: I am updating the packages

Comment: @user330 I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.2’
> packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.1.2’
> packageVersion('purrr')
[1] ‘0.3.4’` on `R 4.0.3`

Comment: I use version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Comment: @user330 Does `dat %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
         names_sep="(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])")` this gives any output

Comment: No, it does not return the output, no error

Comment: I get this Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [2]. I do not have missionf value

Comment: @user330 Do you have only columns `Z1` to `Z8` and `Gol1` to `Gol8` in the dataset.  If that is the case, it should have worked

Comment: I have restarted and now I get this error Error in group_by(., grp, Z) : could not find function "group_by"

Comment: @user330 can you load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: I get this error Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [2]. no ouput

Comment: I am really grateful for your help

Comment: @user330 sorry, it is not clear about the warning if your data is exactly like the one you showed here

Comment: Like this: Z1 Gol1 Z2 Gol2 Z3 Gol3 Z4 Gol4 Z5 Gol5 Z6 Gol6 Z7 Gol7 Z8 Gol8

Comment: @user330 Is there any space between column names and the number ie. `Z 1` instead of `Z1` and `Gol 1` instead of `Gol1` etc

Comment: @user330 that looks like it should work with the same code though.  If you can `dput(head(yourdata))`, it would be more useful to check the structure and test if I can reproduce the same error

Comment: There is no space between Z and Gol and numbers

Comment: like exactly this: Z1 |Gol1 |Z2| Gol2 |Z3 |Gol3| Z4 |Gol4| Z5|Gol5| Z6| Gol6| Z7 |Gol7| Z8 |Gol8

Comment: @user330 It should have worked with either one of these solutions.  As. a test, you can try `df1 %>% group_by(Z1) %>% summarise(Gol1 = mean(Gol1))` and similarly for other 'Z', 'Gol' columns to check if you get error

Comment: @user330 Do you have any grouping attributes.  Can you try `dat %>% ungroup %>%` before the `pivot_longer`

Comment: SUPBERB!. Got it now Issue was GOl and does not have 1. I wish I could give you 10 Upvotes.

Comment: @user330 I guess it was letter `I` instead of `1` right?

Comment: It does not have the number 1 was just Gol

Comment: ok, that makes sense, then both the solutions wouldn't work because in the first case, it is looking for pattern `1` and in the second, it is splitting between the digit and the letter

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `split.default` + `aggregate` + `cbind`

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    unname(split.default(dat, gsub(".*(\\d+)", "\\1", names(dat)))),
    function(x) aggregate(x[2], x[1], mean)
  )
)
```

gives

```
    Z1 Gol1    Z2 Gol2   Z3 Gol3   Z4 Gol4
1 Azam    2  Goli  3.5  Maz  2.0 Carr  0.5
2 Mith    2  komi  3.0 Moli  1.5  Dad  0.5
3 Moli    3 Smith  3.0  Sam  2.0 Moli  0.0
```

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 2) : undefined columns selected. If I inclease columns to 16 instead of 8, I get this error, and sorry